# How to group array elements by index?

Tags: ruby, group-by, slice

I have the array `arr` which I want to group by indexes given in array `idx`. I mean,

- sub array 1 will end at index 1
- sub array 2 will end at index 5
- sub array 3 will end at index 7
- sub array N will be formed from element at index 8 to last element
  of `arr`

With my current code I can group the first sub array with first index of `idx` idx[0] = 1.

Then, How to replicate for all indexes within array `idx`? Thanks in advance.

My current code and output is this:

```
idx = [1,5,7]
arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']

arr.group_by.with_index { |z, i| i <= idx[0] }.values
=> [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]]
```

and my desired output is like this:

```
output   --> [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h"], ["i", "j", "k"]]

#Indexes -->    0    1      2    3    4    5      6    7      8    9    10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`slice_after`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after) to slice the array after each item whose index is in `idx`:

```
idx = [1, 5, 7]
arr = %w[a b c d e f g h i j k]

arr.enum_for(:slice_after).with_index { |_, i| idx.include?(i) }.to_a
#=> [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h"], ["i", "j", "k"]]
```

That `enum_for` is (unfortunately) needed to chain `slice_after` and `with_index`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems to work fine and I think (being new with Ruby) the more compact solution

Comment: Here's a variant: `i = -1; arr.slice_after { idx.include?(i += 1) }.to_a`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
idx = [1, 5, 7]
arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']
from = 0

arr.map.with_index { |a, i|  
  if idx.include?(i)
    result = arr[from..i]  
    from = i + 1 
  end
  result
}.compact

 => [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [9, 3, 1, 6, 2, 4, 0, 1, 5, 8] 
end_idx = [1, 5, 7]
```

```
[-1, *end_idx, arr.size-1].uniq.each_cons(2).
  map { |s,e| arr.values_at(s+1..e) }
  #=> [[9, 3], [1, 6, 2, 4], [0, 1], [5, 8]]
```

The steps are as follow:

```
a = [-1, *end_idx, arr.size-1]
  #=> [-1, 1, 5, 7, 9]
b = a.uniq
  #=> [-1, 1, 5, 9]
c = b.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [-1, 1, 5, 7, 9]:each_cons(2)> 
c.map { |s,e| arr.values_at(s+1..e) }
  #=> [[9, 3], [1, 6, 2, 4], [0, 1], [5, 8]]
```

One can see the elements generated and passed to `map` by  the enumerator `c` by converting `c` to an array.

```
c.to_a
  #=> [[-1, 1], [1, 5], [5, 7], [7, 9]]
```

See [Array#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems to work, the only issue I see is, if `end_idx=[1,5,9]` an empty array `[]` remains at the end within output array.

Comment: Ger, good catch. I made a small change (adding `uniq`) that fixes the problem and also converts `[-1, *[1, 5, 5, 9], arr.size-1]` to `[-1, 1, 5, 9]`.